# Best practice to display the version of a Symfony application to the user?

Tags: php, git, symfony, composer-php, version

We built a web application build on top of the Symfony2 framework.

Now we need to display the current version of our software in the front end for the user to see. The version number is currently a tag in the git repository.

Now what is considered best practice to achieve this? The Composer documentation [discourages the use of the version field](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#version) used in the `composer.json`

Symfony itself seems to set the version string in the `app/bootstrap.php.cache` file:
`const VERSION ='2.7.6';`

Is there any best practice regarding this issue? Is there a way to directly access the git tag name? Or should I go with the constant or `composer.json` way?

Comment: you could look at https://github.com/shivas/versioning-bundle

Comment: To make sure: you want to display the version number of your application? Or the version of a component (i.e. symfony/symfony)?

Comment: I want to display the version of my own application, not the Symfony version. The `versioning-bundle` suggested by @IlyaYarkovets looks very promising, I'll give that a try. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try [versioning-bundle](http://github.com/shivas/versioning-bundle). From their doc:

- Adds additional parameter to your parameters.yml file and keeps it
  inline with your current application version.
- Basic Version handlers
  implemented for manual and git tag versioning

Comment: Neatl - it that tries to automated what I've always done in my projects, putting an `application_version` variable in the `parameters.yml.dist` file. Then of course I always forget to update it when I update my git tag.

Comment: I configured the bundle to generate a separate file (`version.json` in my case) and added this to the `.gitignore` file. This way, you don't have the version string in your git and therefore don't have any inconsistencies. The only thing to remember is to generate the file before deployment, but this could either be automated or you could write yourself a deployment checklist.

Answer (score -2):

with this example now you can do everything :

```
   \Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper::dump(\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel::VERSION);
```

This is a Hardcoded const in source of symfony.

You can :

- code your own const with this
- function for request this info
- trigger or listener
- etc.....

Comment: The question is about how to get access to the version of the application itself that is only defined as a tag in the Git repository.