# How to create/delete "VERSION" file on AWS EB cli deploy?

Tags: symfony, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

After reading this [SO question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35014819/3790921) about website versioning I am using the suggested bundle. It works great on my development env. producing a version number like `0.0.42-dev.2a00d249` however, when i deploy to [AWS EB](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) I loose the version number because the git repository no longer exists.

**Is there any way to automagicaly "copy" the git version and "send" it to EB?**  Maybe via some sort of "pre-deploy" that creates the `/VERSION` file with it in there, but then deletes it?

the `shivas/versioning-bundle` puts priority of the VERSION file over git, thus I loose my git versioning on dev once the file is created.  this is why I'd like to delete it after deploy.

**UPDATE**:
this became way more complicated then it needed to be.  creating and committing the version file was necessary for `eb deploy` to include the file in the first place, but committing it would effectively change the version number generated by the bundle.  I have made some changes to the bundle to automatically write the git version to the version file, reduced the version file priority and ignored the VERSION file in git.  Created the ebignore file and copied everything from gitignore except the VERSION file.  this works, but I have to maintain 2 "ignore" files.  This is still far from ideal.

Comment: how do you get your version number?

Comment: if i understand how it works, try: eb deply -m "`bin/console app:version:status`"

Comment: @NeverBe that will just add the description to the EB App version.

Comment: use eb deply -l "`bin/console app:version:status`". and wrap the command inside the double quotes into the backticks, coz the editor strips it.